# qsort() performance issue

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I'm successfully sorting an array of structs, where each struct only contains a char string. My problem however, is that for a struct array of approx. 900,000 elements, qsort is taking alot longer than I expect (qsort takes about 2 mins to sort this array); leading me to think there is something I am overlooking here.
The sorting is a trivial part of the assignment I am working on, and alone completely over passes the time limit I have for my program.

Below are the relevant parts of my code:

```
struct WordsArray //Just a struct thath holds a *char
{
    char word[25];
};
```

Compare function passed into qsort:

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const struct WordsArray *a1;
    a1 = (WordsArray*)malloc(sizeof(WordsArray));
    const struct WordsArray *b1;
    b1 = (WordsArray*)malloc(sizeof(WordsArray));
    a1 = (struct WordsArray*)a;
    b1 = (struct WordsArray*)b;

    return strcmp(a1->word, b1->word);
}
```

My call to qsort:

```
WordsArray *AllWordsArray;
AllWordsList = (WordsArray*)malloc(sizeof(WordsArray)*ListSize);
qsort(AllWordsList->word, ListSize, sizeof(struct WordsArray), cmpfunc);
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Don't use malloc in your comparison function!

Comment: You're allocating memory inside your comparator function. It is unnecessary, slows your program down and causes a memory leak, since you never free it. Look at the comparator and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your `cmpfunc`'s implementation: it leaks memory faster than a fire hydrant!

You are allocating `(WordsArray*)` pointers only to write over them on the very next line, creating a memory leak in the process. All you need to do is removing `malloc`s:

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct WordsArray *a1 = (struct WordsArray*)a;
    const struct WordsArray *b1 = (struct WordsArray*)b;
    return strcmp(a1->word, b1->word);
}
```

Comment: Why not just cast a and b rather than copy into a1 and b1 (the compiler may do that anyway)? return strcmp(((const struct WordsArray*)a)->word,((const struct WordsArray*)b)->word);

Comment: The casting isn't necessary. It's still C! ;-)

Comment: @rcgldr: "*Why not just cast...*": For the sake of readability I suspect.

Comment: Thanks a million! I had such a hard time with the cmpfunc that once I was able to get something that worked, I ran with it. As for the casting, I will try that.